# What does it mean that a taylor series generated for a function f(x) doesnt converge to f(x)?

Tags: taylor-expansion

If a some function f(x) is continous and has derivatives of all orders on some interval I, and assuming that f(x) can be expressed as a power series on I. And now you generate a taylor series for f(x), this series is may or may not converge on that interval I, to the function f(x).

My question is how can a taylor series generated for a function not converge to that function? That just doesnt seem intuitiv to me. And if it doesnt converge to that function, does it mean it still approximates the function, you can still choose n as high as you want and get a very good approximation of the function f(x), the series just never stops?

Comment: Sadly, no (as to the approximation bit).  Standard example is $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ (and $f(0)=0$).  Not too hard to show that all derivatives exist at $0$  and all derivatives vanish there.  Thus the Taylor polynomials are identically $0$ however far out you go.

Comment: Taylor series attempt to find the polynomial that best approximates $f$ in an open neighborhood of some point $a$. It makes intuitive sense why this doesn't work for a function that is, for example, discontinuous at $a$, because then its behavior near $a$ is not polynomial-like. That is, it's obviously of a different class from the behavior of polynomials. Similarly for $k$ times differentiable functions; their behavior is only polynomial-like up to a point.

Comment: What you're seeing is that there are, in addition, functions which are continuous and infinitely differentiable, but are still not polynomial-like. They have behavior that is somehow fundamentally different than that of a polynomial and thus trying to find a polynomial approximation to the function is doomed to fail. A function that has this type of behavior at $a$ is said to be non-analytic at $a$. Consider carefully that there's not necessarily a good reason to believe that all smooth functions can be approximated by polynomials everywhere.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll  So as long as it is infinitely differentiable you can generate a taylor series for it, the taylor series just doesnt approximate the funciton because it doesnt converge to the function. In other words, for a taylor series to approximate a function it has to converge to it, otherwise its meaningless, eventough it is generated from the actual function?

Comment: @WillJagy I'm starting to get confused here. So far its been established that,any f(x) infinately differentiable on an interval I has a taylor series. That taylor series may or may not converge.

If it doesnt converge does that mean it still approximates f(x)?

Comment: Even if the infinite series has radius of convergence $0$, i.e. doesn't converge anywhere except $x=a$ (which can happen) a finite truncation of that series (a Taylor polynomial) is still a good approximation to $f(x)$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'good approximation.' As already mentioned, the Taylor series for $e^{-1/x^2}$ near $x=0$ is just 0. Every term gives 0. SO is 0 a good approximation for this function near $x=0$? Well in some sense, yes, 0 is the polynomial that best approximates this function near $0$, the error is exponentially small! However, is such an approximation useful? Usually, no, because the Taylor series in this case doesn't give you any information about how the function behaves.

Comment: The question with approximations is always is it "good enough for X," where X is the thing you want to do (compute some value, prove some theorem, etc.). There is no objective, uniform definition of a good approximation. For some uses, approximating $e^{-1/x^2}$ by the polynomial $0$ will be good enough. For other cases it will not be.

Answer (score 1):

Infinitely differentiable functions (of one real variable) are not real analytic (i.e. represented by a power series) for free. You have been exposed to a counter-example in the comments:
$$
f(x)=
\cases{e^{-1/x^2}, &$x \neq 0$ \cr
0, &$x=0$.\cr
}
$$
But real analytic functions can be rather different than holomorphic functions. For example, the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
is real analytic at any point, but its power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}
$$
converges only in the interval $-1\leq x \leq 1$. You can read more [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function).

Comment: So is it the case that 1) real analytic functions are always represented by a Taylor series around any point in a neighborhood of that point, and 2) real restrictions of holomorphic functions are represented everywhere by their Taylor series around any point?

Comment: For real analyticity you must pay attention to the interval of convergence much more than you should in the complex plane, but more or less you are right.

Comment: Can you either explain your comment (especially the first part) a little more, or give me a reference? Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert of real analyticity. You can try to read Krantz's book cited in my link, it is a good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ can be expressed as power series on $I$ (what you assume) then the Taylor series will converge to your function $f$ on $I$ (assuming you expand about the middle of $I$ if $I$ is finite). If $I$ is infinite you can chose every point of $I$ and it will work. Even if $I$ is finite it might be possible to expand about other points then the middle and still get a converging Taylor series on $I$. Also this series converges to your function $f$.

Comment: I thought that eventough f can be expressed as a power series on I, that power series still might not converge on I, and neither does it approximate f, because as it was mentioned in the comments. f may not be possible to approximate with a polynomial, eventough you technically can generate a power series for it as it has derivatives of all orders.

Comment: @ArnoldDoveman The thing that is tripping you up here is the phrase '$f$ can be expressed as a power series on $I$'. This is NOT the same thing as saying that a power series can be GENERATED from $f$. Saying that a function can be expressed as another function is assuming, implicitly, that the two representations are equal. In this case, that means assuming that the power series converges. If the power series does not converge then we should not say that $f$ can be expressed as a power series in this interval, we should use some other verb like 'a power series can be generated from $f$. . .'

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to know Taylor's Theorem with remainder. If the function has many derivatives, we may write approximations with error terms that can sometimes be estimated;
$$  f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(c)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2},   $$
where $c$ is some real number that lies between $x$ and $a$ ( and so depends on both). The error term, with $c,$ is usually called the remainder. there are other ways to write it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder

We get better accuracy near $a$ by using more derivatives,
$$  f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} + f'''(c)\frac{(x-a)^3}{6}.   $$
Here we have returned to $f''(a),$ instead the unknown $c$ between $x$ and $a$ now shows up in $f'''(c).$

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to look at an example of a $C^\infty$ function whose Maclaurin series has radius of convergence $0$.
Consider 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} \cos(n^2 x)$$
Note that this series (which is **not** a Taylor series) converges for all real $x$.  The derivatives are
$$ f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} n^{2k} g_k(n^2 x)$$
where $g_k(t) = \dfrac{d^k}{dt^k}(\cos(t))$ is either $\pm \cos(t)$ or $\pm \sin(t)$ depending on $k$.
This also converges for all real $x$; the function is $C^\infty$.
At $x=0$ the odd-numbered derivatives are $0$, because the function is even, and the even-numbered derivatives are
$$ f^{(2j)}(0) = (-1)^j \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} n^{4j} $$
The absolute value of the coefficient of $x^{2j}$ in the Maclaurin series
of $f(x)$ is
$$ \dfrac{\left|f^{(2j)}(0)\right|}{(2j)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{2^{-n} n^{4j}}{(2j)!} \ge \dfrac{2^{-2j} (2j)^{4j}}{(2j)!} \sim \dfrac{j^{2j-1/2} e^{2j}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}$$
(where I used Stirling's approximation for the factorial in the last step)
and the Root Test shows that the radius of convergence is $0$.